# How to call trigger while inserting a data

Tags: sql-server-2008

my table structure  is like  **itemcode, size , sleeve ,item**  .so people inserting  data like **'S0001','F','96'** at the time of inserting i need to insert item field data like **'S0001-f-96'** how do i write a trigger .

Comment: You start by looking at : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx and trying to do it yourself.

Comment: That looks ripe for implementing as a Computed Column rather than via a trigger.

Comment: ...and the OP's next SO question: I have data like `S0001-f-96` but how do I select out just the `f`...

Answer (score 0):

create  TRIGGER [dbo].[name] ON [dbo].[table] 
for INSERT
AS
    declare @Itemcode varchar(30);
    declare @Itemname varchar(40);
        declare @Slv varchar(1);
        declare @Createdate datetime;
    declare @audit_action varchar(100);

```
select @Itemcode=i.ItemCode  from inserted i;
select @Itemname=i.ItemName from inserted i;
select @Slv =i.U_SLV  from inserted i;
select @Createdate  =i.Createdate   from inserted i;


set @audit_action='Inserted Record -- After Insert Trigger.';

update  OITM_CLONE set sapitem =@Itemcode+'-'+@Slv where itemcode=@Itemcode and u_slv=@Slv and Createdate=@Createdate;

PRINT 'AFTER INSERT trigger fired.'
```

is this right?